# Python Scrapy: I get different results with different methods to fetch pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm building a small crawler wiith Scrapy to use in-house, scraping a subsite on our intranet.
On the pages I'm crawling is this snippet the last element in the page:

```
<span hidden>
xxxxx | 2017-03-15 10:36:57 +0100 (Wed, 15 Mar 2017) | 11
yyyyyy | 2017-06-07 14:54:24 +0200 (Wed, 07 Jun 2017) | 42
zzzzzzz | 2017-10-07 11:51:24 +0200 (Sat, 07 Oct 2017) | 168
aaaaa_bbbb | 2019-02-04 14:27:46 +0100 (Mon, 04 Feb 2019) | 0
</span>
```

When fetching the page through scrapy shell or scrapy fetch, I get the full pages (including the text), but when using the Scrapy.Request within my Spider, the  only and always contains "\n|\n".
This also happens when I try to intercept, using the DownloaderMiddleware class

My Spider looks like this:

```
import scrapy, csv
# from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import signals

class ProjectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ProjectSpider"
    start_urls = [
        'http://cpusrv5.beumer.com/s2000_projects_overview/',
    ]
    projectList = []
    currentProjectIndex = 0
    projectListLength = 0
    currentProjectItem = []


    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        spider = super().from_crawler(crawler)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return spider


    def __init__(self):
        self.outfile1 = open("projects.csv","w",newline="")
        self.state = 1 # 1= projects, 2 = details


    def parse(self, response):
        if self.projectListLength == 0: #OVerview page
                        self.projectList.append(item)


        # Starting up the process of collecting detail-pages
        # print("DONE WITHT THE PROJECT OVERVIEW")
        self.projectListLength = len(self.projectList)
        self.currentProjectItem = self.projectList[0]
        pageToCrawl = response.urljoin(self.currentProjectItem["url"])
        # print("PageToCrawl: " + pageToCrawl)
        yield scrapy.Request(pageToCrawl, callback=self.parse)
    else:
        self.parse_detail_page(response)


    def parse_detail_page(self, response):
        print("Current project: " + self.currentProjectItem["unique_id"] + ' ' + 
        self.currentProjectItem["pname"] + ' ' + self.currentProjectItem["pnum"])

        people = response.xpath('/html/body/span/text()').get()
        print("Full response: \n" + people)

        # Requesting the next page in list
        self.currentProjectIndex += 1
        if self.currentProjectIndex < self.projectListLength:
            self.currentProjectItem = self.projectList[self.currentProjectIndex]
            pageToCrawl = response.urljoin(self.currentProjectItem["url"]+'&index=' + 
               str(self.currentProjectIndex))
            yield scrapy.Request(pageToCrawl, callback=self.parse)
        else:
            print("DONE !")




def spider_closed(self):
    with open("projects.csv","w",newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f,['unique_id','is_guess','pname','pnum','url','maintainer','path','os_guess','first_change','latest_change','latest_change_by','comment','repository','commit log','release log','project portal','servicenow','hotdoc','other documentation'])
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in self.projectList:
            writer.writerow(data)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you write `response.text` into a file from your spider callback? Does the content match what you get from `scrapy fetch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it myself.
Starting from scratch with just crawling one page, the returned  in question was readable.
From there I re-coded my crawler and I think I found the issue: Using 2 parse methods as callbacks when requesting a url.
So what I've done is to use th default parse method as the only callback. To do that I had to change the inner state management, but no big deal.
Anyway, it works !